# How to transform {{{...}}} to markdown code blocks with sed or vim?

Tags: vim, replace, sed, newline, multiline

How can I transform comments like

```
{{{
abc
def
}}}
```

to markdown comments like

```
    abc
    def
```

(4 spaces at the start of each line) in vim or sed?

I tried the following but I didn't get the spaces after the first line:

```
:%s/{{{\n\(\_.*\)\n}}}/    \1/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With vim:

```
:g/{{{/,/}}}/le 4|d|/}}}/d
```

Explanation:

- `:g/{{{/` run a command on each line with the pattern `{{{`
- `,/}}}/le 4` left align from the current line to the ending `}}}`
- `d` delete the current line
- `/}}}/d` search for the line matching `}}}` and delete it

Depending on your indent settings using `>` instead of `le 4` might be sorter.

For more help see

```
:h :g
:h range
:h :left
:h :d
```

Comment: Runs here, but you probably don't want to use `le` because it will lose the indenting. I'm not sure how to use `>` though with the `:g` range.

Comment: According to the documentation: `:left` is not available when `+ex_extra` feature was disabled at compile time. This leads me to believe that your `vim` is either the `tiny` or `small` version. For more information see `:h version`. You can test for `ex_extra` via `:echo has('ex_extra')`

Comment: @DanFitch: Using `:>` can be tricky b/c it moves the cursor to the bottom of recently moved text, so the command becomes: `g/{{{/.,/}}}/>|.d|?{{{?d`. You are right `:left` will blindly destroy the indenting, but it will force 4 spaces from the start of the line.

Comment: That's really cool Peter, I'm going to have to study exactly how it works. What is the `.` before the first `d` doing?

Comment: @DanFitch: Nice catch! I forgot to remove the `.`. The dot represents the current line, which can be inferred without the `.` in this case. So the command becomes: `g/{{{/.,/}}}/>|d|?{{{?d`.

Answer (score 3):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '/{{{/{l=1;next}/}}}/{l=0} l{print"    "$0}' file.txt
```

or less cryptic :

```
awk '/{{{/{l=1;next} /}}}/{l=0} l==1{print "    " $0}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i~ '/^{{{/,/^}}}/{/^{{{\|}}}/d;s;\(^.*$\);    \1;}' inFile
```

Comment: @kirdie: closing `'` was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have no `\r` objects in your text, you can do the conversion with a little help from `tr`:

```
tr '\n' '\r' \
| sed 's/{{{/\r{{{/;
       s/}}}/}}}\r/;
       :w;
         s/\r{{{\r}}}//;
         s/{{{\r\([^\r]*\)\r\(.*\)}}}/    \1\r{{{\r\2}}}/;
       tw' \
| tr '\r' '\n'
```

Note that I added an extra line before and after the code section, or markdown will not recognise the code properly.

Comment: Works too! Although it is a bit longer than the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^{{{/,/^}}}/{//d;s/^/    /}' file
```